# FilteredRowSet is not showing results

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am working on an example using [FilteredRowSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/FilteredRowSet.html), I am trying to run a query, then filter the results using the [Predicate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/Predicate.html) object.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.sql.rowset.FilteredRowSet;
import oracle.jdbc.rowset.OracleFilteredRowSet;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException,
            IOException {
        try (FilteredRowSet rs = new OracleFilteredRowSet();) {
            rs.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe");
            rs.setUsername("dbuser");
            rs.setPassword("dbpassword");

            rs.setCommand("select * from employees");
            rs.execute();

            String name[] = {"user1", "user2"};
            rs.setFilter(new UserFilter("lastname", name));


            while(rs.next()){
                String lname= rs.getString("lastName");
                System.out.println(lname);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Predicate class:

import javax.sql.RowSet;
import javax.sql.rowset.Predicate;

```
public class UserFilter implements Predicate {

    private String[] names;
    private String colName = null;

    public UserFilter(String colName, String[] names) {
        this.names = names;
        this.colName = colName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean evaluate(RowSet arg0) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean evaluate(Object arg0, int arg1) throws SQLException {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean evaluate(Object valueArg, String colNameArg) throws SQLException {
        if (colNameArg.equalsIgnoreCase(this.colName)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.names.length; i++) {
                if (this.names[i].equalsIgnoreCase((String) valueArg)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

In my database table `employees` I have records with `lastName` as values `user1` and `user2` but when I apply the filter as shown in my question, I am not getting any output. I mean the code is not entering the while loop.

Can you please tell me how to apply the filter? I am expecting the output contains the records whose `lastName` contains `user1` or `user2`

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the logic of

```
public boolean evaluate(RowSet arg0);
```

As a best practice, your filter should implement the 3 `evaluate()` methods.

In order to avoid code redundancy in these 3 methods, you can create a private helper method that contains the actual logic of comparing the col/row value with the ones from the filter, and have the 3 `evaluate()` methods call it. For an example look [at this filter](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/Predicateimplementation.htm), that do not factorise the code logic tough.